# How to Rearrange a string and store them in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

I need to parse a string and store them in a 2D double array.
My string is

```
-0.06409677515180673  0.12516724483856012  -0.06188844693840026  0.1542289929525214  -0.06603595481351604  0.07823062287735344  0.10161817634744892  $ -0.33597610014929263

double[][] A =     -0.06409677515180673
                    0.12516724483856012  
                   -0.06188844693840026  
                    0.1542289929525214  
                   -0.06603595481351604  
                    0.07823062287735344  
                    0.10161817634744892
double [][] B = -0.33597610014929263
```

both of them should be a column 2D array.

I tried spliting with $ but it is not working.
what i tried

```
String getpart = "my string";
double[][] A = null;

String[] parts = getpart.split("\\$");
            String part1 = parts[0];
            String part2 = parts[1];
           /*checking for part 1*/
            int i = 0;
            StringTokenizer st= new StringTokenizer(part1," ");
            String getdata = null;
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                int j=0;
                getdata = st.nextToken();
                A[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(getdata);
                i++;
            }
```

But showing null pointerexception in `A[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(getdata);`

Any suggestions?

Comment: why is this a 2 dim array?

Comment: Why 2D array? I think 1D is enough.

Comment: `split` takes a **regex**, try to split with `\\$`.

Comment: yes it is 1 dimension. but for further computation i need them as 2D

Comment: How do you intend to store your doubles in array A?

Comment: Hey NSK, I removed [solved] from the title. We don't do that on Stack Overflow because it creates clutter and confusion. Instead, when you mark an answer as accepted, the question will appear on the main page as answered, so this isn't really needed anyway. Hope this helps clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
This is the working code.

```
String stringToSplit = "-0.06409677515180673  0.12516724483856012  -0.06188844693840026  0.1542289929525214  -0.06603595481351604  0.07823062287735344  0.10161817634744892  $ -0.33597610014929263";

        String[] splitArrayPhaseA = stringToSplit.split("\\$");
        String part1 = splitArrayPhaseA[0];
        String part2 = splitArrayPhaseA[1];

        /*
         * Part 1
         */
        String[] innersplitpart1 = part1.split("  ");

        String[][] omegastr = new String[innersplitpart1.length][];
        int omegar = 0;
        for (String omegakeyrow : innersplitpart1) {
            omegastr[omegar++] = omegakeyrow.split("  ");
        }

        String[] innersplitpart2 = part2.split("  ");

        String[][] gamastr = new String[innersplitpart2.length][];
        int gamar = 0;
        for (String gamakeyrow : innersplitpart2) {
            gamastr[gamar++] = gamakeyrow.split("  ");
        }
        /*
         * part1 and part2 to double
         */

        double[][] A = new double[omegastr.length][omegastr[0].length];
        double[][] B = new double[gamastr.length][gamastr[0].length];

        for(int vali =0;vali< omegastr.length ;vali ++){
               for(int valj = 0;valj <omegastr[0].length;valj++){
                  A[vali][valj] = Double.parseDouble(omegastr[vali][valj]);
               }

           }
        for(int valgi =0;valgi< gamastr.length ;valgi ++){
               for(int valgj = 0;valgj <gamastr[0].length;valgj++){
                   B[valgi][valgj] = Double.parseDouble(gamastr[valgi][valgj]);
               }

           }
        System.out.println(omegastr.length+":"+omegastr[0].length);
        System.out.println("Part 1");
       for(int vali =0;vali< A.length ;vali ++){
           for(int valj = 0;valj <A[0].length;valj++){
               System.out.print(A[vali][valj]+ "\t");
           }
           System.out.println(""); 
       }
       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("Part 2");
       for(int vali =0;vali< B.length ;vali ++){
           for(int valj = 0;valj <B[0].length;valj++){
               System.out.print(B[vali][valj]+ "\t");
           }
           System.out.println("");
       }
```

output

```
7:1
Part 1
-0.06409677515180673    
0.12516724483856012 
-0.06188844693840026    
0.1542289929525214  
-0.06603595481351604    
0.07823062287735344 
0.10161817634744892 

Part 2
-0.33597610014929263
```

Answer (score 4):

For splitting using $ as the delimiter you will have to use the escape character '\' in the regex.

```
String[] inputs = input.split("\\$");
```

Once you have splitted using '$', You can then split using space to get each double value

```
inputs[0].split(" ");
```

Comment: Nearly correct. The second split gives you again a string[] which then can be parsed to their double values. Somebody who has issues with declaring an array (like the OP in the question), needs every step at least mentioned to understand the solution.

Comment: ys upto 2 nd split i am getting. but how to know about the dimensions. they can very each time

Comment: You need to provide us entire details as why you need a 2 dimensional array. From the usecase provided by you single dimension array should suffice.

Comment: @NSK, trying splitting with white space `\\s+` as i have shown, then you will have an array of double value using which you can get the `dimension`

Answer (score 1):

> tried spliting with $ but it is not working

in Java, for an instance `str` of `String`, `str.split(String regex)` function splits string around matches of the given regular expression `regex`, for finding a pattern to be matched with the given pattern. However, Regular expression allows finding pattern by specifying location by matching known as *[boundary matchers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html)*. `$` is such a boundary matcher which represents `The end of a line`. If you however want to bypass it's usage as a boundary matcher, you need to escape it. For example, `str.split("\\$")`

After splitting you should have an array `s[]` with strings split on `\\$`, you will have to split each String of `s` with `\\s+` for splitting with white space :

```
    String s[] = str.split("\\$");

    String dVal[] = s[0].split("\\s+");
    double A[] =  new double[dVal.length];

    int i = 0;
    for(String data: dVal)
    {
        A[i++] = Double.parseDouble(data);
    }
```

**Reference:**

1. [Boundary Matchers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    String stringToSplit = "-0.06409677515180673  0.12516724483856012  -0.06188844693840026  0.1542289929525214  -0.06603595481351604  0.07823062287735344  0.10161817634744892  $ -0.33597610014929263";
    String[] splitArrayPhaseA = stringToSplit.split("\\s*\\$\\s*");

    String[][] stringValues = new String[splitArrayPhaseA.length][];
    double[][] doubleValues = new double[splitArrayPhaseA.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < splitArrayPhaseA.length; i++) {
        stringValues[i] = splitArrayPhaseA[i].split("\\s+");
        doubleValues[i] = new double[stringValues[i].length];
        for (int j = 0; j < stringValues[i].length; j++) {
            doubleValues[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(stringValues[i][j]);
        }
    }

    double[][] a = new double[1][];
    double[][] b = new double[1][];
    a[0] = doubleValues[0];
    b[0] = doubleValues[1];

    for (double doubleValue : a[0]) {
        System.out.println("First array in 2D array [a] element value: " + doubleValue);
    }
    for (double doubleValue : b[0]) {
        System.out.println("First array in 2D array [b] element value: " + doubleValue);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Updated the code to store result in 2D arrays a and b.
The result of running the code should yield:

```
First array in 2D array [a] element value: -0.06409677515180673
First array in 2D array [a] element value: 0.12516724483856012
First array in 2D array [a] element value: -0.06188844693840026
First array in 2D array [a] element value: 0.1542289929525214
First array in 2D array [a] element value: -0.06603595481351604
First array in 2D array [a] element value: 0.07823062287735344
First array in 2D array [a] element value: 0.10161817634744892
First array in 2D array [b] element value: -0.33597610014929263
```

Comment: This will split the string into a 2D double array. Please, if you are going to downvote, post a comment of why you want to do so.

Comment: Oh, and the code is tested and works. I am sure you can read the code and figure out how to put it to use for you.

Comment: Also note that in the first pass I am splitting with \\s*\\$\\s* in order to remove unwanted whitespace elements. The same goes for \\s+ in the second pass.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but why you need to split `\\s*\\$\\s*` instead of `\\$` in the first place. If there are unnecessary extra space, they will be removed by your second split call `\\s+` automatically.

Comment: I tried to print doubleValues . but showing array indexoutofbound I need the doublevalues array(need my array as 2D double) but in 2 different 2 D array.after # it should go into 2 nd array B

Comment: I need to split initially with \\s*\\$\\s* to remove whitespace. If I don't do this, the second split with \\s+ will generate an empty element if the string to split (the second string generated from the first split) starts with whitespace.

Comment: My comment about downvoting was ment for the downvoter :) I honestly do not know who it was..

Comment: ys u are really right . But my a array should be 2 dimensional itself.a[][] and b[][]

Comment: so according to my input a is of 7 by 1 matrix and b is of 1 by 1 matrix

Comment: The dimension of a is [1][7] and the dimension of b is [1][1]. If you want your data stored differently, then from this point it is a matter of allocating array slots and rearranging the parsed double values into the correct array slots.